# How to store field of tuples of models in Django models?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm working on a web for translators. I'm stucked on designing a structure of the data. So there is a model Translator, Language and Level. The price depends on Language and Level (Standard level multiplies the price 1x, Professional 1.5x etc.)

Each Translator can translate multiple languages with different levels (skills).

I can't figure out how to design models for this purpose. My idea is to store for each Translator some field of tuples (Language,Level) so the model Translator would be:

```
class TranslatorProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userprofile')
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=40,null=True,blank=True)
    IBAN = models.CharField(max_length=40,null=True,blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    # HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    languages = models.FieldOfModelTuples(Language,Level)

class Level(models.Model):
     LEVEL_NAMES = (
            ('standard', 'Standard'),
            ('professional', 'Professional'),
            #etc.
        )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=LEVEL_NAMES)
    price_multiplier = models.FloatField()

class Language(models.Model):
    shortcut = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I would appreciate any advice how to solve this problem (.`FieldOfModelTuples` does not exists of course). Maybe there is a simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I think that `Level` should be a field on a through-model for a many-to-many relationship between `TranslatorProfile` and `Language`:

```
class TranslatorLanguage(models.Model):
    translator = models.ForeignKey('app_name.TranslatorProfile')
    language = models.ForeignKey('app_name.Language')
    level = models.ForeignKey('app_name.Level')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('translator', 'language'),)
```

this allows you to query all necessary properties for each `Translator`-`Language` pair. Access to a translator's languages can then be simplified via:

```
# HERE IS THE PROBLEM
languages = models.ManyToManyField(Language, through='TranslatorLanguage')
```

Comment: In fact, this does not work. It says that 'TranslatorLanguage' is not defined. It is because the 'TranslatorProfile' is defined before 'TranslatorLanguage' but it tries to call it. And the same but opposite problem when I swith this two models. If there is 'TranslatorLanguage' before 'TranslatorProfile', It says that 'TranslatorProfile' is not defined...

Comment: Well, as a general rule, you should provide the to-model of a relation field as a String `'app_name.model_name'` to avoid these issues.