# How to properly define through-model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm facing a problem when I'm trying to define through-model in Django. I've posted a question couple hours ago and the answer was to define a through class. But the problem is, that this through-model calls already defined models and one of these models which are defined before this through-model is calling this through-model.

```
NameError: name 'TranslatorLanguage' is not defined
```

If I switch them:

```
NameError: name 'UserProfile' is not defined
```

[THIS IS THE ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36498543/3371056) (In fact it's not a `TranslatorProfile` but `UserProfile`)

Do you know what to do?

I'm attaching models.py in case it helps:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
# from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class AdminContact(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

class Language(models.Model):
    shortcut = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class Level(models.Model):
    LEVEL_CHOICES = (
        ('standard','Standard level'),
        ('professional','Professional level'),
        ('native','Native speaker level'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40,choices=LEVEL_CHOICES, blank=False, null=False)
    price_multiplier = models.FloatField()



class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userprofile')
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=40,null=True,blank=True)
    IBAN = models.CharField(max_length=40,null=True,blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    MARITAL_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('single', 'Single'),
        ('married', 'Married'),
        ('separated', 'Separated'),
        ('divorced', 'Divorced'),
        ('widowed', 'Widowed'),
    )
    marital_status = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=MARITAL_STATUS_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)

    HOW_DO_YOU_KNOW_ABOUT_US_CHOICES = (
        ('coincidence', u'It was coincidence'),
        ('relative_or_friends', 'From my relatives or friends'),
    )
    how_do_you_know_about_us = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=HOW_DO_YOU_KNOW_ABOUT_US_CHOICES, null=True,
                                                blank=True)

    # TRANSLATOR ATTRIBUTES

    is_translator = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    language_tuples = models.ManyToManyField(LanguageTuple,blank=True)
    languages = models.ManyToManyField(Language, through='TranslatorLanguage')

    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    number_of_ratings = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)

class UserProfileLanguage(models.Model):
    userprofile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)
    level = models.ForeignKey(Level)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('UserProfile', 'language'),)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use string of model instead of model class itself to refer to the foreign key. It's specially true when you have definition sequence problem. Quoting from [django doc foreign key section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey):

> If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been
>   defined, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model
>   object itself:
>
> ```
> from django.db import models
>
> class Car(models.Model):
>     manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(
>         'Manufacturer',
>         on_delete=models.CASCADE,
>     )
>     # ...
>
> class Manufacturer(models.Model):
>     # ...
>     pass
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to specify the `TranslatorLanguage` model as a string, since it is defined later in `models.py`, like this:

```
languages = models.ManyToManyField(Language, through='TranslatorLanguage')
```